# Server Error in '/' Application. Could not find a part of the path

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to delete XML files on button click, the files are in the XML folder on my site (in smarterasp.net hosting) using this code :

```
Protected Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim directoryName As String = MapPath("~/xml/")
    For Each deleteFile In Directory.GetFiles(directoryName, "*.xml", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
        File.Delete(deleteFile)
    Next
    Label1.Text = "done"
End Sub
```

**but I got this error :**

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\karary-001- 
site1.htempurl.com\xml'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about 
the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a 
part of the path 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\karary-001- 
site1.htempurl.com\xml'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web 
request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can 
be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 
'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\karary-001-site1.htempurl.com\xml'.]
System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +219
System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit() +268
System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String 
originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, 
SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost) +434
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern, SearchOption 
searchOption) +86
WebApplication1.addTimetable.Button4_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in 
C:\Users\MONZER\Desktop\Karary Web 
Site\WebApplication1\addTimetable.aspx.vb:65
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9815014
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) 
+204
```

**what is right way to get the folder, I have tried those :**

1- http://karary-001-site1.htempurl.com/xml/

2- h:\root\home\karary-001\www\site1\xml\

3- ~/xml/

Comment: I think it's correct `Server.MapPath("/xml")`, try that way.

Comment: @DouglasThomas Thomas Thanks you save my life !!